# Cleanest way of dealing with an IAsyncOperationWithProgress?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-runtime, async-await

I've been using C# for quite a while, but somehow have not yet had the pleasure of using the whole `await/async` thing new in .Net 4. Well, now I'm making a console application that links to the WinRT libraries and WinRT is really.. well, asynchronous.

One thing I'm needing to do right now is install a package. So, I use `PackageManager.AddPackageAsync` This is of course asynchonous and returns an `IAsyncOperationWithProgress`

I know I could do something like

```
bool Done=false;
void Foo()
{
    var tmp=new PackageManager.AddPackageAsync(...);
    tmp.Completed= ... FooBar;
    while(!Done){}
}
void FooBar(...)
{
    Done=true;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure the whole async and await thing was designed for exactly this scenario. However, I don't understand how to use it in this context on an `IAsyncOperationWithProgress`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net includes a `GetAwaiter()` extension method that makes `IAsyncOperationWithProgress` awaitable.
You can just write `await tmp;` in an `async` method.

Your `async` method will return a `Task` (or `Task<T>`), which you can `await` from another async method, or call `Wait()` to synchronously block.

Comment: With that(and after adding a reference to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`), I get the error `System.Runtime.CompilerServices<Windows.Management.Deployment.DeploymentResult>' does not contain a definition for IsCompleted`

Comment: Ah, also had to add a reference to System.Threading.Tasks (the WinRT version).. Linking to WinRT from a desktop app is such dark territory heh

Comment: @Earlz running into the same trouble, where can I find the WinRT version of System.Threading.Tasks?

Comment: @SteveStifler: Try http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx

Comment: I added the reference but the problem persisted. I've asked a question that has further details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817780/using-winrt-on-the-desktop-with-lockscreen-api

Answer (score 2):

Async and Await allows you to program an Async operation as if it occurs on the calling thread. First you have to declare your operation as being async then you await the async operation from the other guy. Finally you do whatever work you wanted to do after that operation is complete.

```
async void Foo()
{
  var tmp=await new PackageManager().AddPackageAsync(...);
  //do something else;
}
```

Calling Foo will make it run in the background, but when AddPackageAsync completes, Foo rejoins the calling thread (e.g. the UI thread) to complete its work.

The other option is to call GetAwaiter extension method and call Wait() on it to manually block until the operation completes.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to that progress by using an overload of AsTask method, like the following

`...= await new PackageManager().AddPackageAsync(...).AsTask(new Progress<DeploymentProgress>(...))`;