# Using WinRT on the Desktop with LockScreen API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm writing a toy desktop app that interacts the `LockScreen` API, which is part of WinRT and uses `async/await`. After following the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx), I've enabled support for WinRT and added the following references:

```
System.Runtime.dll
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
```

However I still get this error while building:

`'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter' does not contain a definition for 'IsCompleted'`

The error is associated with the `await` line of my code. What else am I missing?

Edit: Here's the code in question and the full list of references for the project.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.System.UserProfile;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

public class Program : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Program()
    {
        string wallpaper = ...
        ...

        SetLockScreenImage(wallpaper);
    }

    private async void SetLockScreenImage(string path)
    {
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        ...

        await LockScreen.SetImageStreamAsync(ras);
    }
}
```

References

```
Microsoft.CSharp
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtension
System.Deployment
System.Drawing
System.Runtime
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
System.Windows.Forms
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
Windows
```

Comment: Can you share the code with a full list of references added?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Have you tried adding the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package, that adds full support for async/await on some missing platforms? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Answer (score 0):

I have found that setting target platform to x64 on 64-bit PC could resolve the issue. Developers on [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4df4323b-35cb-4816-b01c-082312109931/win8-desktop-app-use-lockscrrengetimagestream-problem?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) were solving a similar problem as you are having, although for Windows 8 Consumer Preview, so it is hard to tell, if the solution is still valid.